# How to control worker transactions with jdbc data source?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

when use spark delete(or update) and insert , Either all sucess ,Either all fail.

And I think spark application is distributed across many JVM, how can  control the every worker transaction  synchronize?

```
// DELETE: BEGIN
Class.forName("com.oracle.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
String query = "delete from users where id = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setInt(1, 3);
preparedStmt.execute();
// DELETE: END

val jdbcDF = spark
  .read
  .jdbc("DB_URL", "schema.tablename", connectionProperties)
  .write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "DB_URL")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .save()
```

Comment: Since you mention the concept of "transaction", why don't you control your custom JDBC connection with something like `conn.setAutoCommit(true)` or `conn.createStatement().execute("commit")`?

Comment: Basically, if the driver runs a connection (for your custom DELETE) and multiple executors run a connection (for the `.save()` applied to their local DF partitions), then from Oracle point of view, these are distinct connections running distinct transactions. You cannot coordinate them at DB level. All you can do is coordinate them at **application** level, e.g. replace the DELETE with "INSERT INTO tmp + DELETE + commit", then attempt `.save()` in parallel, and in case something fails, "DELETE the partial save + INSERT SELECT FROM tmp + commit"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** You can't.

Spark is [a fast and general engine for large-scale data processing](http://spark.apache.org/) (i.e. a multi-threaded distributed computing platform) and the main selling point is that you may and will surely execute multiple simultaneously running tasks to process your massive datasets faster (and perhaps even cheaper).

JDBC is not very suitable data source for Spark as you are limited by the capacity of your JDBC database. That's why many people are migrating from JDBC databases to HDFS or Cassandra or similar data storage where thousands of connections is not much of an issue (not to mention other benefits like partitioning your datasets before Spark will touch the data).

You can control JDBC using some [configuration parameters](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) (e.g. `partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, `numPartitions`, `fetchsize`, `batchsize` or `isolationLevel`) that give you some flexibility, but wishing to "transaction synchronize" is outside the scope of Spark.

Use JDBC directly instead (just like you did for DELETE).

Note that the code between `DELETE: BEGIN` and `DELETE: END` are executed on the driver (on a single thread).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll take your suggestion and use jdbc directly.